# Функция работает некорректно

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Такой код:

```
import socket
import math

addrlist = []
buf = []

def Decimal():
    global res
    global addrlist
    count = 0
    numbers = [int(c) for c in addrlist] #[140, 82, 118, 3, 31, 13, 72, 36, 104, 25, 5, 14]
    for x in numbers:
        if count == 0:
            res = x * math.pow(16, 6)
        if count == 1:
            res += x * math.pow(16, 4)
        if count == 2:
            res += x * math.pow(16, 2)
        if count == 3:
            res += x
        count += 1
        if count == 6:
            count = 0
        res8 = 'http://' + str(int(res))
        print(res8)
    input()

def listurl():
    global buf
    handle = open('ad.txt')
    for x in handle:
        buf.append(x)
    handle.close()
    buf = map(lambda buf: buf.strip(), buf)
    buf = list(buf)

def getipforlist(ip):
    global addrlist
    temp = socket.gethostbyname(str(ip))
    temp = temp.split('.')
    addrlist += list(temp)

listurl()
for x in buf:
    getipforlist(x)
Decimal()
```

Вывод консоли:

```
http://2348810240
http://2354184192
http://2354214400
http://2354214403
http://2354214403
http://2354214403
http://1207959552
http://1210318848
http://1210345472
http://1210345497
http://1210345497
http://1210345497
```

Но он работает не исправно. Как сделать так чтобы функция работала с множественными значениями?

PS С одним значением она работает.

```
import math

res = 0

def Decimal():
    global res
    count = 0
    addr2 = ['140', '82', '118', '4']
    numbers = [int(c) for c in addr2]
    for x in numbers:
        if count == 0:
            res = x * math.pow(16, 6)
        if count == 1:
            res += x * math.pow(16, 4)
        if count == 2:
            res += x * math.pow(16, 2)
        if count == 3:
            res += x
        count += 1
    res = 'http://' + str(int(res))
    print(res)
    input()

Decimal()
```

Вывод: `http://2354214404`

```
[140, 82, 118, 3, 31, 13, 72, 36, 104, 25, 5, 14]
```

Это `[140, 82, 118, 3] [31, 13, 72, 36] [104, 25, 5, 14]`

Если я пропущу эти значения(3 списка выше) через функцию,то она выдаст правильные результаты, но мне надо чтобы когда я ставил в значении список(выше, где объединены 3 списка в 1 список), он также выдавал корректные значения.

Корректные: `http://2354214403 http://520964132 http://1746470158`
Но функция(самая первая), которая должна работать с одним сплошным списком этих значений(3 списка в 1) выводит это:

```
http://2348810240
    http://2354184192
    http://2354214400
    http://2354214403
    http://2354214403
    http://2354214403
    http://1207959552
    http://1210318848
    http://1210345472
    http://1210345497
    http://1210345497
    http://1210345497
```

Comment: В чем выражается "неисправно"? Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать **желаемое поведение**.

Comment: Эта функция должна выдавать такие значения как и функция ниже(только должна выдавать их много, не одно значение), а на данный момент она выдает неправильные значения.

Comment: Если вам кажется, что от такого объяснения стало понятно, то вы ошибаетесь. Какие "такие"? Почему они неправильные?

Comment: У меня есть функция, которая конвертирует значения в decimal, если в с списке будет например ['140', '82', '118', '4'], то она выдаст правильный результат, но если в списке будет [140, 82, 118, 3, 31, 13, 72, 36, 104, 25, 5, 14] т.е много значений (каждый 3 элемент отдельно), то функция выдает неправильные значения.

Comment: Нужно а) добавить эту информацию в вопрос, б) объяснить, почему выданные значения неправильные и какие значения должны быть на самом деле.

Comment: Добавил больше информации в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде несколько ошибок.

1. Нужно обнулять res после вывода каждого значения.
2. Новая последовательность должна начинаться после 4-х значений, а не после 6.
3. Выводить нужно только итоговое значение, а не все промежуточные.

Исправленный блок кода:

```
for x in numbers:
    if count == 0:
        res = 0
        res = x * math.pow(16, 6)
    if count == 1:
        res += x * math.pow(16, 4)
    if count == 2:
        res += x * math.pow(16, 2)
    if count == 3:
        res += x
        res8 = 'http://' + str(int(res))
        print(res8)
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        count = 0
```

Результат:

```
http://2354214403
http://520964132
http://1746470158
```